# Debugging release build of windows exe built with bazel using visual studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, bazel

I'm building a Windows exe using Bazel (release 4.1.0). I'm building by first opening the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt For VS 2019" in order to set the environment to use VS 2019 build tools and then use that command prompt to compile via

```
bazel --bazelrc windows.rc build --verbose_failures -c opt myproject:mytarget
```

in my `windows.rc` I added the following lines:

```
# Enable "Whole program optimization"
build --copt /GL
# Enable Link Time Code Generation
build --linkopt=/LTCG
#embed debug symbols
build --copt /Z7
build --strip=never
```

and this causes the resulting exe to get significantly bigger. But when I then attach the Visual Studio 2019 Debugger to the process, Visual Studio nevertheless tells me `Binary was not built with debug information.`

What else do I need to do to be able to attach the debugger and have debugging symbols loaded?

Note: I specifically want to create a release build (-c opt) with all optimizations, but have symbols included (like described here for Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-debug-a-release-build?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Debugging information is generted by `-c dbg`

Comment: @Vertexwahn yeah but that generates a debug build. I want to generate a symbolized release build (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-debug-a-release-build?view=msvc-160)